# How to change the font and size of chapters and list of tables, content, figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, fontsize

How can I change the font of all of my `\addchap{ }` (chapters) to the font "Times" and the size of it (preferably `\large` and **bold**)?

The List of Figures, List of Tables and the Table of Contents should also have the same structure, as described above.

Here an example of my code. (If you need more of the code please tell me, I might have missed something).

```
\documentclass[12pt,chapterprefix]{scrreprt} % for bigger size of text 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listtablename}{Tables}

\begin{center}
\listoftables
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\listoffigures
\end{center}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{ \Large \filcenter}{}{1em}{}%\sffamily
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\filright \itshape }{}{1em}{} 
%\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\filright \bfseries }{}{1em}{} <- if that code is used, yes the size changes, but my "Chapter [Number]" (see picture) disappears on the page itself but not in the toc.

\begin{center}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{center

 %chapter in toc and on page (numbering)
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}

\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}#1\autodot}{#2}}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\addchap{Introduction}\setcounter{page}{1} % unnumbered chapter
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second part of your question about the structure of the lists and TOC? It's not clear what you'd like them to be like. (Or do you mean that the heading of the lists and TOC should look the same as the chapter's headings?)

Comment: Yes, I would like the heading of the TOC, and the lists (figures/tables) also to be bold and large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a KOMA Script documentclass, see "Table 3.2.: Elements whose font style can be changed" in the KOMA Script Manual (which can be found here: [https://komascript.de/~mkohm/scrguien.pdf](https://komascript.de/%7Emkohm/scrguien.pdf)).

(Note that the `times` package is [obsolete](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/times), I changed it to `newtxtext` in this answer, you could also consider using Stix Two Text.)

You don't need `titlesec` for what you want, instead add `\setkomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily \large}` to your preamble:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily \large}
\usepackage{blindtext}%just to add a sample document

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want *all* of the headings in your document (chapters, sections, subsections, ... etc.) to use the serif font as your body text then you can use the option `sfdefaults=false` with the documentclass (thanks to Sam Carter for pointing out the changed name of this class option):

```
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\large}
\usepackage{blindtext}%just to add a sample document

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Both of those will also change the listoftables and listoffigures headings (those are chapters too).

(Also note that changing the default behaviour of chapters will have you redefining sections, subsections, and so on as well, otherwise they look weird in relation. Are you sure you want to change the default settings that much?)

Comment: this is a great solution!                                                                                        I just would like no numbers in my \sections only the title (enumerations appeared). Also, it does not say in \Chapter ->  Chapter 1 Theoretical Framework but 1 Theoretical Framework. How could I solve that problem?

Comment: Also, in a bold enviroment like this, how can I make \addtokomafont{subsection}{\itshape } -> non-bold

Comment: @KarlL. I'm glad this helped you. No numbers in sections: add the option `\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{}` and use sections like `\section[nonumber=true]{text}`. Non bold: `\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalfont \itshape}`

Comment: @KarlL. However, tex.sx is not meant to be a forum, but an expanding collection of references to problems. By answering the same questions over and over again this site loses its value... The same applies for multiple problems being addressed in the same question, or as comments. Instead, PLEASE have a look at previous questions on this website (as well as documentations of packages you're using) and if you run into a problem post it as its own question.

Comment: Okay, I did not know that it is not like "forum", just signed up. thanks for telling me! \section[nonumber=true]{text} does not seem to work, the \normalfont works, though

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`

Comment: Thank you, Sam! That is a very good point and I'll update the answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 1):

It is too long for additional comments to the question.

**Warning:** *Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class.*

It seems that only chapter headings should be bold. Then you can use

```latex
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}
```

Note that font element `disposition` is used by all elements for headings, eg. `chapter`, `section`, `subsection` etc.

To change the font of elements for headings (like `chapter` or `section) you can use either` \setkomafont`and`\addtokomafont`or you can add option`font`to`\RedeclareSectionCommand` which is already used in the example.

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\bfseries\large,% does the same as \setkomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\large}
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}
```

You could also add options to change the vertical space before and after the chapter heading. Please read the documentation for more information.

Settings for sections and subsections:

```latex
% section
\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\sffamily\Large]{section}% does the same as \setkomafont{section}{\sffamily\Large}
% subsection
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %indent=1em,% <- add this if the subsections should be indented
  font=\itshape% changes the font, does the same as \setkomafont{subsection}{\itshape}
]{subsection}
```

To center `section` headings but not `subsection` and `subsubsection` headings use

```latex
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\centering #3#4}% centers section headings
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
}
```

If only chapters (and parts) should be numbered add

```latex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}
```

to the preamble.

Do not use `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` in enviroment `center`. Their headings are centered by `\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}` automatically. If the pages in ToC, LoF and LoT should use page style `empty` use

```latex
% use page style empty in in ToC, LoF and LoT
\AfterTOCHead{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}
```

Remove `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}` and `\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}`. If you really want to redefine `\figurename` use

```latex
\renewcaptionname{english}{\figurename}{Figure}% Figure is default?
```

`\listtablename` was already redefined by `\renewcaptionname`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  chapterprefix,
  sfdefaults=false% no sans serif headings etc., needs version 3.39 or newer
  ]{scrreprt} % for bigger size of text 
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{newtxtext}% <- changed
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}% only parts and chapters should be numbered

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\mdseries}% headings of section, subsection etc. should not be bold

%chapter in toc and on page (numbering)
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\bfseries\large,% does the same as \setkomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\large}
  tocentrynumberformat={\def\autodot{:}},
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}% center chapter headings
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}

\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}
    {\originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}#1\autodot}{#2}}%
}

% section
\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\sffamily\Large]{section}% does the same as \setkomafont{section}{\sffamily\Large}
% subsection
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  %indent=1em,% <- add this if the subsections should be indented
  font=\itshape% changes the font, does the same as \setkomafont{subsection}{\itshape}
]{subsection}

% format headings with style=section, eg. section, subsection and subsubsection
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\centering #3#4}% centers section headings
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}% original definition for other section levels
}

% use page style empty in in ToC, LoF and LoT
\AfterTOCHead{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}

% rename LoF and LoT
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\listtablename}{Tables}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\cleardoubleoddpage% <- changed
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addchap{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

[image]